# Как добавлять +1 к полю модели PositiveIntegerField при добавлении каждой новой записи?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model

Есть модель Posts. Для произвольной сортировки создано отдельное поле Order = models.PositiveIntegerField.

**Задача:** в модели переопределяя метод Save - осуществить добавление индекса +1 (от последнего имеющегося индекса) в данное поле при добавлении каждому новому посту.

```
def save(self):
        super().save()
```

То есть - у каждого поста должен быть ещё Order-index, и если уже имеется 3 поста на сайте, то при добавлении четвертого - у него добавляется в поле индекс 4, и так далее.

Помогите осуществить эту логику. Вроде простая, но не знаю как подступиться.

Comment: Думаю лучше искать максимальный, и к нему уже добавлять

Comment: @ZaArs Да, именно, self,order.objects.latest(self.order) как-то так думаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тогда можно как то так. Сортируем и находим объект с наивысшим значением и присваем его значение +1

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    max_order_obj = type(self).objects.order_by('-ordering').first()
    if max_order_obj:
        self.ordering = max_order_obj.ordering + 1
    else:
        self.ordering = 1
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Можно улучшить до получения только значения `ordering`

Comment: А для чего здесь используется type(self)? Если не трудно, объясните пжл, а то встречал и с type(self) и без.

Comment: Вообщем, работает! Спасибо! Помогли!
Но так и не понял ещё зачем включать type(self)...

Comment: В принципе, если в объекте есть `objects` можно через `self`. Пишу `type(self)` по привычке, чтобы обращаться от класса, а не от объекта

Comment: Почему `type(self).objects.order_by('-ordering').first()` а не `Post.objects.order_by('-ordering').first()` ? В чем разница? @za-ars

Comment: я написал 23 часа назад

Comment: разница лишь в том , чей objects берется, из Post класса  или объекта